# GetEnumerator returns null

Tags: c#

Object `htmlDocument.Body.All` is not null. Why does `GetEnumerator()` return null?

```
IEnumerator<HtmlElement> hm =  htmlDocument.Body.All.GetEnumerator() as      
IEnumerator<HtmlElement>;
```

Comment: There are 3 `HtmlElement` classes in the .NET framework that I can see, and that's the only specific type identified in your code fragment. Would you care to add a bit more info so that we even know which classes you're using here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this. Although why you want an `Enumerator<HtmlElement>` I have no clue.

```
IEnumerator<HtmlElement> hm =  htmlDocument.Body.All
               .OfType<HtmlElement>()
               .GetEnumerator();
```

In most cases you will find that you can do things much more easily with

```
foreach(var element in htmlDocument.Body.All.OfType<HtmlElement>())
{
     //Stuff
}
```

Comment: Because I want to parse html into my model.

Answer (score 1):

You are casting it using `as` and if `as` fails, it returns `null`. Try it like this, to see what the exact return type is without assuming anything or casting:

```
var hm =  htmlDocument.Body.All.GetEnumerator();
```